# How to middle align text and the markers and place the legends for this?

Tags: plotting, functions, legending

How can I middle align the legends and markers? 
 Changing the font size make it not aligned.

[image]

```
ClearAll[legend1]
Options[legend1] = {Joined -> Automatic};
legend1[colors_, polymarkers_, legend__, , OptionsPattern[]] := 
 PointLegend[colors, legend, Joined -> OptionValue[Joined], 
  LegendMarkers -> (ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][#, Offset[4], 
       EdgeForm[]] & /@ polymarkers), LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 30}, 
  LegendLayout -> (Column[Row /@ #, Spacings -> -1.5] &)]
colors = ColorData[97, #] & /@ Range[6];
polymarkers = {"DownTriangle", "SevenPointedStar", "FourPointedStar", 
   "Diamond"};
mylegend = 
  MaTeX[TeXForm[#], Magnification -> 0.5] & /@ {{"5X", "6Y", "8Z", 
     "9M", "2K", "2N", "2T", "3N", "5O"}, {"1X", "3Y", "5Z", "2L", 
     "9K", "3Z", "7X", "3P", "2T"}, {"3K", "6M"}, {"3H", "6K"},
    {"X4", "Y5", "C6", "1K"}, {"X6", "Y6", "C6", "Z6"}};
legend1[colors, polymarkers, mylegend, , Joined -> True ]
```

Another question:
Do you have any idea to make the legend more constrast to the background? 
(please ignore the not matching between the lines and the markers ) 
I thought about adding background for legend but there isn't much space left. Also I don't want to place the legend outside of the plot and I want to keep the image size unchanged.

```
Legended[Plot[{x, 2 x - 1.5, x - 1, 1 - x, x - 2, 1/2 x - 1}, {x, 1, 
   5}, GridLines -> {Range[1, 5, 1], Range[1, 5, 1]},
  PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0, 5}},ImageSize -> 360], 
 Placed[legend1[colors, polymarkers, mylegend, , 
   Joined -> True ], {0.2, 0.8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing the Magnification option and changing this: `LegendLayout -> (Column[Grid[{##}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}] & /@ #, Spacings -> 0] &)`

Comment: @user5601 but I want to use magnification somewhere as well.